# xyplot and inter-panel spacing when setting different scalings

Tags: r, lattice

After getting xyplot to use different ylim for each lattice row (that part works),
i end up with some additionnal spacing between the panels that i can't seem to be 
able to get ride of. In the example below, i would like to

- (a) remove the three spacing between each column
- (b) get the axis labeling on the 9th panel (i.e. the one one line 2, column 4) to appear on the right hand side of the plot.
- (c) ensure that each panel starts at exactly 0 and ends at exactly 10 (on both x and y):  and not -0.1 and 10.1 as is the case now.

Thanks in advance,

> library(lattice)
>
> library(latticeExtra)
>
> ```
> B<-structure(list(yval = c(9.04558240029191, 0.799530758536875, 
> 4.69069522598669, 1.91643037953314, 1.57786714979593, 1.8446918362001, 
> 12.2500411978512, 3.07665190473454, 3.28898861276143, 6.01549253849571, 
> 8.17821235705288, 3.79595798212791, 0.805594114806692, 6.41198823745342, 
> 3.28568215145447, 7.98224159193929, 8.60366317617762, 5.42388511534892, 
> 0.764825548373361, 3.9666691576256, 2.47156955689964, 7.27503578997147, 
> 5.44633450784916, 6.60905274634776, 5.45786814114277, 0.758864205932014, 
> 2.84057319554552, 5.04212318294901, 7.00770048354209, 4.38241850904838, 
> 12.3629788063877, 0.761708333337782, 6.33197137795722, 6.67224995833747, 
> 5.34251622052521, 8.66662936109525, 13.5204012323942, 4.0032083141389, 
> 11.6843895681122, 12.8329939259479, 9.09319429081734, 4.8090480682483, 
> 1.10183130102097, 2.85680676388518, 6.0430350387286, 0.864262666632898, 
> 4.03505027841203, 7.83331437064888, 0.99216416521435, 8.1203144160401, 
> 5.7347651851128, 13.0677987321833, 5.45030129828113, 6.78666709316608, 
> 9.13141740602399, 3.96553096986173, 5.67648924810184, 4.02795185222417, 
> 1.19923217249904, 8.00633581508868, 3.62564568701185, 0.945006814343432, 
> 11.6861884359709, 9.17683187930724, 4.11952821761626, 9.48867838961486, 
> 9.14151956014416, 9.93838160762052, 4.60891102702602, 6.99239234030028, 
> 1.00586875673025, 8.57168767869193, 2.22835635254303, 10.7135685293467, 
> 5.87713139624508, 3.14952893096586, 6.81194443415328, 3.36658738967144, 
> 1.57839234760371, 4.65736854147361, 13.6432997178854, 1.15264945152674, 
> 7.20595566631243, 0.925980641981997, 0.869008955269436, 4.75095327168301, 
> 8.81030618436026, 3.92273652447446, 8.12949426073657, 5.76933378419949, 
> 0.777256448291363, 2.38339350715339, 0.734001474102335, 9.52159088621359, 
> 9.04970565702903, 6.90866926838569, 5.9005334817271, 7.00203106927033, 
> 8.99155252630509, 8.94266111063583, 5.92279271877979, 4.42034111796866, 
> 6.75839811937969, 8.64658069020977, 6.73162187983837, 7.81184984214652, 
> 7.98579728627022, 3.37676029593063, 0.786919300835254, 6.26305128304185, 
> 4.34845809230566, 3.95541090231129, 6.72281577578086, 0.695707197714119, 
> 10.0560573020158, 4.15810837453519, 0.873004867283037, 4.16327733595061, 
> 6.49503064101967, 8.12090562610595, 6.97504423312718, 5.04835565620835, 
> 4.1951025387306, 3.4389006143913, 14.2771156202001, 7.03956347153237, 
> 4.38618618413419, 2.37913020416628, 5.76940052627782, 6.7843580672236, 
> 5.6189786720292, 0.858382930463266, 8.93422023821023, 6.66122216464326, 
> 4.65890006006495, 2.49108732055206, 5.20714425399159, 6.76817735008579, 
> 4.57887132963062, 8.17948756574428, 0.898004842730052, 2.87380239133325, 
> 4.60134531154924, 6.10512608065437, 9.25669653387974, 4.02358360379974, 
> 1.65752932816245, 13.0180323775825, 1.07835183694634, 6.77152818032083, 
> 0.992191765039423, 9.30217478579486, 0.97874136454804, 0.866890009992784, 
> 8.817554894806, 0.7272450310133, 8.44736877413528, 0.920962179334358, 
> 6.74426140262635, 11.4976862396927, 6.83227936730633, 6.65379134595895, 
> 8.08853124664082, 8.42288560540892, 6.74875380809505, 2.36799257646616, 
> 4.36076052102911, 5.37997507455859, 2.74739395725121, 0.711432451231922, 
> 0.88339933260502, 3.99251745639107, 6.00066182640637, 4.70148688755132, 
> 1.49531958692362, 4.63991117659694, 6.85411354349471, 6.46882156338255, 
> 6.85653606216362, 4.00308723827046, 4.48618366295549, 10.111122152813, 
> 6.18726852405011, 4.21496939061236, 8.08951972351983, 5.75062772615253, 
> 5.52475848522626, 1.26794710186864, 9.01653579750459, 6.11422725714239, 
> 9.53492872517571, 0.880694109464262, 6.81404895940322, 5.87046596781633, 
> 0.987684218656088, 0.905904225040102, 0.709536461897921, 9.54425897216572, 
> 2.42394501347149, 2.39393463069561), xval = c(7.47963566160188, 
> 7.53843824926937, 7.89102425119663, 0.714250331034379, 0.350808447161537, 
> 0.920278439461499, 2, 1.18120433837389, 2.15668307822314, 3.53934453115817, 
> 4.54534178644686, 6.35156921947863, 6, 5.85193346902148, 0.257061197908195, 
> 4.31405462193795, 7.44504037562708, 1.6419865257507, 5.92245885664568, 
> 5.85762870655473, 2.41500543375237, 2.05255225180268, 2.61260633367393, 
> 7.38952812116483, 3.40841861174166, 5.56641353876732, 1.06334634355079, 
> 1.22092009561206, 7.14905823173125, 7.77833375224301, 6.48602609472388, 
> 2.22876858735943, 4.63608825703697, 7.20409587755302, 3.94029557829791, 
> 5.49693346564516, 8, 3.68168379693831, 4.53399156590835, 2, 3.20232386763659, 
> 3.11465409149307, 3.59096547110588, 0.970635458843625, 3.79609219567095, 
> 7.55431365252621, 3.84830138707843, 8, 9.68422707545899, 6.45952162701766, 
> 2.61260633367393, 8, 2.80146412397853, 2.71523669358035, 3.34195216347927, 
> 5.7052168115031, 4.83629254883881, 3.00634266399471, 0.161521370138566, 
> 2.77915434648176, 0.430882606717923, 6.40468404364395, 8, 1.82254474904725, 
> 2.02274863777057, 0.0952104996681957, 1.18810690234325, 4, 0.707737916689389, 
> 6.61645186383278, 6.80447998235695, 5.0388851286179, 8.33100258777955, 
> 2.88309613397185, 2.50046471894888, 1.43831427763256, 8.80421484592245, 
> 2.43273028649955, 3.18832058131858, 0.721572350979251, 8, 1.907891777796, 
> 1.05560820975072, 9.99619906048348, 6.68527581003685, 8.69201244754421, 
> 5.84110748159124, 8.0167791392137, 6.33916453325404, 2.2417758680228, 
> 5.0575474022438, 0.434518494934576, 7.63978081682492, 5.19955013543875, 
> 7.49576429936454, 8.70020957978785, 2.56269498257904, 6.90165751709627, 
> 7.3319320403241, 6.9801288946986, 0.251493263610557, 5.70219219685056, 
> 9.07813067781478, 9.68422707545899, 7.69678435668618, 4.88668899911176, 
> 2.6243179089804, 1.80110071603502, 4.64623158623263, 6.40047515568851, 
> 2.07682859084626, 3.3080241101838, 7.45291987882876, 3.20531761919078, 
> 8.70020957978785, 7.65805776625107, 9.51348984354148, 7.75570667603492, 
> 5.23744300265713, 3.66772339261955, 9.96838812401567, 1.22757975659896, 
> 2.10117458601233, 4.30252110036365, 8, 9.7853969925673, 7.8498968972544, 
> 1.06023998229514, 2.80808561311523, 8.936106857321, 4.33847136469, 
> 2.28195392443262, 2.71065687399482, 7.11534497790504, 0.736599072564448, 
> 0.0371367578969133, 1.66833297125009, 2.25721316147136, 1.25087606440674, 
> 0.196049047891455, 9.47293734757645, 1.68846238246007, 8.39657940508961, 
> 2.99332681317713, 6, 6.21814736208532, 0.582872210285507, 2, 
> 6.70176650693179, 7.25659815967902, 1.89552337969659, 6, 7.64691089050179, 
> 5.90288700711154, 4.50475630428356, 4.71258989491385, 4.40677648764997, 
> 9.96001027491324, 8.20245208325319, 2, 8.09144329864304, 7.05910754176663, 
> 3.38701780181836, 4.272006377931, 8.98520317584308, 0.59821501073407, 
> 9.81164531780974, 4.19141637809377, 1.44318685936535, 8.79864437508768, 
> 3.21596961924959, 1.99186824405878, 3.28063130382249, 8.05841625618546, 
> 0.106451981669153, 7.18587595643851, 2.35872287708421, 7.46774138570701, 
> 8.19156257322725, 3.09809701159013, 9.1323987488354, 9.33479740023197, 
> 3.40547170163811, 2.23290070547077, 6.82128728998622, 0.175226827422645, 
> 1.93267256652364, 3.29266684711463, 4, 4.71250021739426, 4, 8.96389342027811, 
> 7.6410830341138, 2.2417758680228, 3.92681182511134, 8.23603091257415, 
> 9.29870572131864, 5.33258781492592, 1.78141216060964, 1.86262944881485
> ), gval = c(2, 4, 2, 4, 4, 3, 1, 2, 4, 3, 4, 2, 3, 2, 2, 2, 3, 
> 2, 1, 4, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 4, 4, 3, 4, 2, 1, 1, 3, 2, 1, 1, 4, 2, 
> 1, 1, 1, 4, 3, 2, 3, 1, 2, 4, 4, 4, 3, 4, 2, 3, 1, 4, 4, 4, 4, 
> 4, 2, 1, 4, 4, 1, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 1, 4, 1, 3, 3, 4, 4, 1, 2, 
> 4, 1, 4, 3, 3, 2, 4, 2, 4, 3, 1, 3, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 1, 1, 1, 
> 2, 2, 1, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 1, 4, 3, 4, 2, 4, 3, 3, 
> 1, 2, 4, 3, 2, 4, 3, 3, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 2, 4, 4, 1, 2, 4, 
> 2, 3, 4, 1, 1, 3, 2, 3, 3, 3, 1, 4, 3, 1, 3, 4, 1, 2, 2, 4, 1, 
> 4, 2, 4, 4, 2, 4, 1, 4, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 2, 4, 2, 1, 2, 4, 4, 
> 1, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 4, 3, 4, 1, 4, 4), type = structure(c(2L, 
> 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
> 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 
> 2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 
> 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
> 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 
> 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
> 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
> 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 
> 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 
> 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 
> 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 
> 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 
> 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("0", "1", "5"), class = "factor"), 
>     cr = structure(c(3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
>     3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
>     3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
>     3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
>     3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
>     3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
>     3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
>     3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
>     3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
>     3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
>     3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
>     3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
>     3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
>     3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("0.2", 
>     "0.3", "0.4"), class = "factor"), p = structure(c(4L, 1L, 
>     3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
>     2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 
>     3L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
>     1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 
>     1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 
>     2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 
>     1L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 
>     3L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 
>     4L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 
>     4L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 
>     3L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 
>     4L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
>     3L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 
>     3L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("4", "8", "12", "20"), class = "factor"), 
>     nsamp = c(500, 100, 300, 500, 100, 200, 100, 300, 200, 200, 
>     300, 100, 100, 200, 500, 500, 500, 200, 100, 200, 300, 100, 
>     100, 500, 100, 100, 300, 100, 200, 200, 500, 100, 300, 200, 
>     500, 200, 100, 300, 500, 100, 300, 500, 300, 300, 200, 200, 
>     300, 100, 100, 300, 100, 100, 100, 500, 300, 100, 500, 100, 
>     100, 300, 100, 300, 100, 500, 500, 500, 500, 100, 200, 200, 
>     300, 200, 100, 500, 300, 500, 200, 200, 300, 300, 100, 200, 
>     200, 200, 200, 300, 500, 100, 300, 300, 300, 200, 100, 300, 
>     500, 300, 300, 200, 200, 200, 200, 300, 200, 100, 200, 500, 
>     300, 300, 100, 500, 100, 100, 200, 100, 300, 200, 200, 200, 
>     300, 300, 200, 100, 500, 100, 100, 300, 200, 100, 100, 200, 
>     100, 100, 300, 200, 200, 500, 100, 500, 100, 300, 200, 100, 
>     300, 300, 100, 200, 500, 100, 500, 300, 100, 100, 300, 300, 
>     500, 300, 200, 200, 500, 100, 500, 200, 300, 200, 200, 300, 
>     200, 500, 100, 100, 200, 500, 200, 300, 300, 300, 500, 100, 
>     500, 100, 200, 300, 300, 500, 300, 200, 100, 500, 100, 200, 
>     100, 300, 300, 300, 100, 300, 100, 300, 100, 100), grp = c(4, 
>     2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 5, 2, 2, 4, 4, 2, 5, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 2, 2, 
>     2, 4, 4, 2, 4, 2, 2, 4, 4, 2, 4, 2, 4, 4, 2, 4, 5, 2, 4, 
>     5, 4, 2, 2, 2, 4, 2, 2, 5, 4, 4, 4, 5, 4, 4, 4, 4, 2, 4, 
>     2, 4, 4, 2, 5, 4, 2, 4, 4, 5, 4, 4, 2, 4, 4, 4, 4, 2, 4, 
>     2, 2, 4, 5, 2, 4, 2, 2, 2, 4, 2, 4, 4, 2, 2, 2, 4, 4, 4, 
>     4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 2, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 2, 2, 2, 4, 4, 4, 2, 4, 
>     2, 2, 2, 4, 4, 4, 4, 2, 2, 5, 4, 2, 2, 4, 4, 4, 2, 4, 4, 
>     4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 2, 2, 2, 4, 5, 2, 2, 5, 2, 4, 2, 5, 2, 
>     2, 4, 2, 4, 2, 2, 5, 2, 4, 4, 4, 4, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
>     4, 2, 2, 2, 4, 4, 2, 4, 2, 4, 4, 2, 4, 4, 4, 2, 5, 4, 5, 
>     2, 4, 4, 2, 2, 2, 4, 2, 2)), .Names = c("yval", "xval", "gval", 
> "type", "cr", "p", "nsamp", "grp"), row.names = c("25155", "42789", 
> "46517", "49502", "42342", "44189", "592", "46071", "44843", 
> "20664", "23997", "41460", "1395", "20144", "24836", "25020", 
> "25616", "19868", "40797", "45051", "45473", "16611", "17292", 
> "48391", "17346", "42670", "47427", "17848", "21588", "44011", 
> "24651", "40559", "23361", "20239", "48249", "19450", "2250", 
> "46260", "24569", "341", "21971", "49634", "46933", "46054", 
> "20688", "43408", "46269", "2415", "19049", "24104", "17941", 
> "2403", "17304", "25413", "21976", "18791", "49720", "18616", 
> "42333", "23874", "17149", "45734", "2278", "25830", "48149", 
> "25754", "24413", "853", "20484", "21549", "47123", "19415", 
> "18976", "24497", "23212", "49071", "21704", "44856", "45532", 
> "22469", "2120", "43066", "21186", "44723", "44522", "46582", 
> "26012", "41553", "24096", "23192", "45652", "44153", "40894", 
> "22105", "25156", "23616", "23216", "21565", "19570", "19542", 
> "19091", "46373", "20365", "17102", "20965", "25512", "23861", 
> "47489", "42599", "49788", "18560", "18638", "20934", "41880", 
> "22330", "45179", "44688", "45185", "22749", "23931", "21101", 
> "17849", "48153", "41313", "2005", "23698", "44019", "42378", 
> "17954", "21032", "17413", "41830", "21941", "20231", "20490", 
> "25283", "17236", "24924", "18500", "23724", "43509", "41155", 
> "47923", "22598", "1823", "45077", "48067", "578", "49321", "22867", 
> "41806", "1821", "47180", "45705", "25957", "47004", "19369", 
> "44718", "49865", "250", "48907", "20225", "23910", "19360", 
> "21714", "46026", "45295", "49690", "41142", "42888", "43145", 
> "49575", "20651", "46530", "46000", "46472", "24929", "18267", 
> "48912", "18621", "44081", "22380", "22625", "49588", "24130", 
> "19088", "17899", "49170", "953", "20072", "1201", "45925", "22901", 
> "22549", "42555", "47227", "42921", "22112", "42430", "42436"
> ),class = "data.frame")
> ```
>
> mypanel<-function(...){

```
  if(current.row()<3){
        panel.grid(v=-1,h=-1,col="dark grey")
        panel.xyplot(...)   

  } else {

        panel.grid(v=-1,h=-1,col="dark grey")
        panel.bwplot(...,pch="-",cex=3,
        fill=cl,horizontal=FALSE,
        stats=adjboxStats)  

   }
```

}

edited format

```
ato<-rep(list(NULL),12); ato[[8]]<-ato[[1]]<-ato[[9]]<-TRUE;
alte<-rep(list=c(2),12); alte[[8]]<-list(2);
lmi<-rep(list(c(0,10),c(0,10),c(0,20)),4); 
useOuterStrips(xyplot(B$yval~B$xval|B$p*B$grp,group=B$gval,
  type=c("l","g"),lwd=2,cex.lab=1.5,as.table=TRUE,
  par.settings=list(plot.symbol=list(pch="*",col="black",cex=1),
  box.umbrella=list(lty=1,col="black",lwd=2),cex=2,
  par.xlab.text=list(cex=1),axis.text=list(cex=1),
  par.ylab.text=list(cex=1)),panel=mypanel,
  scales=list(y=list(relation="free",limits=lmi,at=ato,alternating=alte))))
```

Comment: Can you provide the function (or object) `mypanel`?

Comment: @Ben how do you manage to edit the code to make it look nice?

Comment: I took out the quote symbol ">" and indented each code line by four spaces (the last 6 lines I indented 6 spaces). Then added line breaks. SO did the rest!

Comment: maybe this one will help: http://thebiobucket.blogspot.com/2011/04/r-graphs-lattice-use-of-panel-functions.html

Comment: @Kay: i tried what is posted on this website you link to, but for some reasons, the inter-panel spacing is still there, even when i try to adapt that code :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, here is a possible solution.

- (a) To get rid of the horizontal space, add `layout.widths=list(axis.panel=0)` to your `par.settings`.
- (b) To get the axis labels to the right for the plot in row 2, column 4, there's an inelegant solution below
- (c) To get exact limits, add `axs="i"` to the `x` and `y` components of `scales`.

In summary:

```
ato<-rep(list(NULL),12); ato[[1]]<-ato[[9]]<-TRUE;
```

Above, I removed the assignment to `ato[[8]]`

```
lmi<-rep(list(c(0,10),c(0,10),c(0,20)),4)
useOuterStrips(xyplot(B$yval~B$xval|B$p*B$grp,group=B$gval,
  type=c("l","g"),lwd=2,cex.lab=1.5,as.table=TRUE,
  par.settings=list(plot.symbol=list(pch="*",col="black",cex=1),
  box.umbrella=list(lty=1,col="black",lwd=2),cex=2,
  par.xlab.text=list(cex=1),axis.text=list(cex=1),
  par.ylab.text=list(cex=1),layout.widths=list(axis.panel=0,
  right.padding=3)),panel=mypanel,
  scales=list(y=list(relation="free",limits=lmi,at=ato,axs="i"),
  x=list(axs="i"))))
```

And the inelegant axis solution:

```
trellis.focus("panel", 4, 2, clip.off=TRUE,highlight=FALSE)
panel.axis(side="right",at=pretty(lmi[[8]]),outside=TRUE)
```

p.s. From `?xyplot`:

> alternating applies only when relation="same".

Therefore, I took it out of the code.

**EDIT:**

I forgot to mention that I added `right.padding=3` to the `par.settings` to make room for the axis ticks and labels. If you need more room on the right, simply substitute a larger number for 3. In order to get more space on the left, you could tweak `left.padding` as well.